# Capacitor for 5v power supply

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

Sorry to ask a question that I feel I should be able to google, but I'm kind of stuck.
I have some different 5v AC/DC power supplies that I need to plug into the wall and use to power rgb LEDs.
The max currents that I need to draw from these supplies are 2,4A, 1,2A, 0,9A, 0,6A, so I use one power supply 2,5A, one 1,5A (this one is variable 3-12V, I'm assuming that I get minimum 1,2A at 5v) and the rest 1A.
What value capacitors do I put across 5v and gnd in these particular circumstances?
I get that they should be rated for 10v as a safety, but I don't know how to get to a good number on capacitance. No datasheets available to me on the power supplies, but on the 1A supply it says 300mV ripple on the web site where I buy them.
Thanks!

EDIT: Schematic

EDIT2: Updated schematic
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Why do you need capacitors besides what's already in your power supplies? Draw a circuit diagram.

Comment: Ok I'm drawing, will take a while... I'm not sure why I need it, but the examples I have seen of these circuits typically use capacitors near the power source. I'm new to circuit design and I'm quite nervous to stick anything I made into the wall. :)

Comment: The power supply should already have capacitors near the power source to regulate the voltage.

Comment: 300 mV is unlikely to cause any problems. Having three power supplies connected in an unknown way on the other hand is.

Comment: @winny Added schematic, let me know what you think! Did it really fast though, and it's my second ever attempt, so not sure I got everything right...

Comment: You share ground and have divided the load accordinly, that's good. Could you consider having resistors in series from your Atmel output pin to the data input pins of your LEDs? Might not be 100 % necessary but it's always a risk using several supplies that one have lower voltage than another and you end up "shorting" them together via an I/O pin.

Comment: Right, forgot that now, my previous schematic had the resistors on the data lines. And as for the capacitors, it seems that the consensus is that I don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

These are regulated DC power supplies so you probably don't need additional capacitors in your circuit. The wall-wart already has capacitors built in. 300mv ripple may not be noticeable if you're simply driving an LED string- in any case that level won't destroy anything you're likely to be working with. Give it a try sans capacitors first, see if it works, worry about ripple later.